# How do I use a 3rd party 3-clause BSD license in a LGPL project?

Tags: lgpl, bsd

I'm thinking of publishing my project (VSCode extension; binary and source) under LGPL. My code "statically links" a static library that is licensed under 3-clause BSD.

1. Does that work?
2. How does it work @ source?
3. How does it work @ binary?

#### 1. Can I use 3-clause BSD licensed code in a LGPL project?

From [this](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/5420/26118) I understand that I can use a 3-c-BSD library within a GPL project. )

#### 2. How do I "implement" the license for the source?

- Is it enough to add a license file directly next to the library location?
- Do I need to add the license statement somewhere in the root directory of the project?

##### 3. How do I "implement" the license in the binary?

How do I "ship" the 3-BSD license with my binary? Do I simply add a license text file that I distribute with the binary?

##### Notes

Other questions of kind get comments like "ask a lawyer". 
**I don't expect a legally binding answer**. But a rationale to the answer would be very nice. 
If we all need lawyers to get through the free software license jungle we could stop it altogether